# timeseries count of Grafana Loki logs grouped by error type

Tags: grafana, logql

I want a view similar to this: [image: Timeseries data with count]

with a different colour/line for each error type

I tried 2 approaches and failed

#### 1st Approach - transformers

1. I first query all by requests and present the verb

   ```
   {job="myJob", filename="/server.log"} |= `exception_type` | json | line_format 
   `{{.exception_type}}`
   ```
2. Then I use a `Format Time` transformer, where I set the formatting to `YYYYMMDD-HH`
3. Then I use the `Group By` transformer, where I group by my now grouped by hour Time as well as `line` which contains the `exception_type`

   - I also add a `calculate` on the "Id" column and select `count`
   - lastly I add a `calculate` on the "Time" to get the first value

At this point I have a few of the columns I need, but no way for the Timeseries ingest this format.

#### 2nd Approach - multiple `count_over_time` stacks

I could technically stack a bunch of these (one for each error type), but that seems less than ideal; both because I don't have a comprehensive list of error types, and because the maintenance surface area is larger than I'd like

```
sum(count_over_time({job="myjob", filename="server.log"} | json | exception_type =~ "Could not create folder" [$__interval]))
```

The image I provided works because it's hitting an SQL DB (Postgres) which has a group by and a query that looks like this:

[image: postgres query]

Comment: You described what you tried very well, but you mostly missed what you want/need.

Comment: If that is something like "graph for number of messages with exception_type by exception_type", have you tried `sum by (exception_type ) (count_over_time({job="myjob", filename="server.log"} |= `exception_type` | json [$__interval]))`

Comment: @markalex that's exactly what I was missing!! Didn't realize you could do a `sum by` on the outside like that. Will read up more in the docs. Feel free to submit that as the answer and I'll accept it